# WordPress Performance dilemma

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

I currently worry about performance. The situation is currently:

I want to display content from block editor, or from Gutenberg WordPress editor.

I created a page template and connect with a page.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php the_content();?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What is best way to add elements from **the_content();** fun. classes.

eg. I wanna headings tags have an example class but paragraph tags have others. 
I have three ideas how to ''fix'' this.

First:

Add style tag inside page template and target elements by CSS.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
<style>
    .main h1 { color: red; } .main p { color: green; }
</style>
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="main">
          <?php the_content();?>
     </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Second:

Add the target class by jQuery.

```php
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="main">
          <?php the_content();?>
     </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<script>
     $("h1").addClass("color-red");
     $("p").addClass("color-green");
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Or add a class from Gutenberg editor. But I am not sure, what if the user deletes the entire element. Not just content.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, *the simpler, the better*.

I would use the theme's `styles.css` file or another already existing one and only add a class to the `main` div in the template (`example` class here).

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="main example">
          <?php the_content();?>
     </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So that you are able to target each element of your html in your CSS file

```
.main.example h1 { color: red; } 
.main.example p { color: green; }
```

Comment: What about if I have defined classes for headings or paragraphs?